# how to transfer symfony project

Tags: symfony1, web-deployment

I have an application built on symfony which was deployed by my coder. Now, i want to transfer my application to another server. I dont have the original project files and only the application which was deployed by my coder.

My question is, how can i setup the same application on another server with the files i currently have. I have [google](http://www.google.com) and did not get any useful info.

Any help will be appreciated.

The application was built on symfony 1.0.17

Answer (score 0):

The following steps are quite high level and assume you know how to dump/restore databases, install software and check configurations for your database and webserver.

You don't say if your application has a database, so I'll assume it does.

In order to move it to another server, you would need to:

< on the new server >

1. Check you have the right software on your new server
2. Setup webserver, database, etc
3. Setup a Symfony 1 environment on your new server

< on the old server >

1. Stop the webserver
2. Take a database dump
3. Take a copy of the symfony 1 project (using zip or tar)

< on the new server >

1. Create a new database instance
2. Restore the database dump
3. unzip/untar code to right place
4. Start webserver

< other stuff>

1. Change DNS pointer from old to new server
2. Clean up old server

I hope this was useful and helps.